# ¿Cómo se obtiene el contenido que está dentro de un paréntesis?

Tags: javascript, array

Me dan un array de frases con espacios en blanco, las cuales tienen entre paréntesis las soluciones a dichos huecos (Ej.: `"We (can) do it!"`).

El ejercicio me pide que extraiga esas palabras para poder compararlas con la solución introducida por el usuario y ver si es correcta. Sé que una manera de hacerlo es con `indexOf`, pero no sé cómo aplicarlo.

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta y agregar lo que has intentado para que podamos ayudarte a identificar donde esta el error.

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creo que lo que necesitas es manipulación de `includes` y de `split`, te dejo la mejor solución que yo encontré

```js
//almacenas el valor de la respuesta en una variabe
var cadena = "We (can) do it!";
//validas que la cadena contenga el parentesis de apertura
if (cadena.includes('(')) {
    //divides la cadena en tantos elementos como delimitador del parentesis contenga quedando asi.
    //cadenaTemp[0]='We ' /*/  cadenaTemp[1]='can) do it!'
    var cadenaTemp= cadena.split('(');
    //asiganas a la cadena el segundo valor
    cadena = cadenaTemp[1]; //'can) do it!'
    //validamos que el resto de la cadena tenga el parentesis de cierre el cual tambien dividira
    if (cadena.includes(')')) {
         //cadenaTemp[0]='can' /*/  cadenaTemp[1]=' do it!'
        var cadenaTemp= cadena.split(')');
        //capturamos el valor que necesitamos
        cadena = cadenaTemp[0];
    }
}
console.log(cadena);//'can'
```

espero te sirva, me cuentas...

Comment: Gracias!! Me es de mucha utilidad

Comment: Me alegra mucho @RicardoHerrer, marca la pregunta como resuleta, para que salga de la lista de pendientes del SO

Answer (score 0):

Esta es mi repuesta: puedes utilizar una expresión regular para encontrar el texto entre paréntesis, y después recuperas el `substring` desde el carácter 1 hasta el penúltimo.

```js
let cadena = "We (can) do it!";
//la expresión regular utiliza un grupo de captura para capturar el contenido dentro de las paréntesis.
let rex = /\(([\w]+)\)/
//encuentra el texto entre paréntesis
let texto = cadena.match(rex)[0].replace(rex, "$1");
//recupera el substring desde el carácter 1 hasta el penúltimo.
console.log(texto);
```

Y este es un ejemplo donde el usuario prueba responder la pregunta:

```js
let cadena = "We (can) do it!";
let rex = /\(([\w]+)\)/
let solucion = cadena.match(rex)[0].replace(rex, "$1");
// al escribit algo en el input
elInput.addEventListener("input",()=>{
//utilizo trim() por si hay espácios delante y detras del texto
  let respuesta = elInput.value.trim();
  if(respuesta == solucion){
 console.log("OK")}
})
```

```html
<p id="elP">We <input id="elInput" type="text" /> do it!</p>
```